# How can display the HTML page in Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Actually, I'm trying to display the data to angularjs HTML page. In Angularjs CTRL page have the data to pass html page i have passed the data but not showing.

Below Angular CTRL code :

Below data is console.log data:console.log(response); the firstName and lastName and all showing but siteName &siteurl is not showing.

```
**console.log(response);**

data: {id: "7", credit: "0.00", firstName: "Rahul", lastName: "Joshi", email: "rahul@gdiz.com"}
siteName: "EveryDay Lunch"
siteurl: "https://test.hotlunch.com/credits"
```

This is my HTML page code:

```
<p>Hello {{lowcreditCtrl.data.firstName}} {{lowcreditCtrl.data.lastName}}</p>
<p> Hello {{lowcreditCtrl.data.siteName}}</p>
<p>{{lowcreditCtrl.data.data.siteurl}}</p>
```

Comment: hi palash, nothing will come

Comment: what does `<pre>{{lowcreditCtrl}}</pre>` returns?

Comment: `siteName` and `siteurl` are not in the data object.

Comment: Hi Rob Moll, How can i pass the data siteName  & siteurl  please..

Comment: `data: {id: "7", credit: "0.00", firstName: "Rahul", lastName: "Joshi", email: "rahul@gdiz.com", siteName: "EveryDay Lunch", siteurl: "https://test.hotlunch.com/credits"}` This gets them both in the data object, but I'm not sure if that's your intended logic. Also doing this will cause this to fail: `<p>{{lowcreditCtrl.data.data.siteurl}}</p>` because it's looking at `data.data...`

Comment: ok thanks next step what i have to do this display data in html page

Comment: Did you see what `<pre>{{lowcreditCtrl}}</pre>` returns as suggested by @palash?

Comment: Hi Rob Moll, I did  this <pre>{{lowcreditCtrl}}</pre>  output is showing like this pls check it not coming  siteName &  siteurl  -----"data":{"id":"7","credit":"0.00","firstName":"Rahul","lastName":"Joshi","email":"rahul@gdiz.com"}

Comment: Do you get that when you use `data: {id: "7", credit: "0.00", firstName: "Rahul", lastName: "Joshi", email: "rahul@gdiz.com", siteName: "EveryDay Lunch", siteurl: "https://test.hotlunch.com/credits"}` ?

Answer (score 0):

As per your log , you need a following may be I think,

Hello {{siteName}}

{{siteurl}}

Try it or please send a js complete function and json return complete screen shot.

Comment: Oh ! Will try it . It's works on my project. Can you please send your script function.